# Using Azure Automation Account, Copy files from one Fileshare to another Fileshare across Storage

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-storage, azure-automation, fileshare

I am trying to copy one file (x) from a fileshare (y) of storage (z), to a fileshare (a) of storage (b).

```
$StorageAccountName = "z"
$StorageAccessKey = 
"md226fZvTKPKaCd9TxDGPn4mitCPfvBvgzElwoqIgpbf2Pe09GKKfNJlMcK2EXXqRLqOrhBslybaE1Cpz2BcPg=="
$context1=New-AzureStorageContext $StorageAccountName $StorageAccessKey

$DestStorageAccountName = "b"
$DestStorageAccessKey = "xZjU0r5g5fU+/ieAbwc22OmVtFY5BJdQuF8OZsFd7hGHYLzQFGg9ZCpsVnQi5u6Wi/nigb8jdupUGo0YaXBphg=="
$destcontext1=New-AzureStorageContext $DestStorageAccountName $DestStorageAccessKey
$SrcPath = "https://z.file.core.windows.net/y/x"
$SrcShare = "y"
$DestPath = "https://b.file.core.windows.net/a"
$DestShare = "a"
Start-AzureStorageFileCopy -SrcFilePath $SrcPath -SrcShareName $SrcShare -DestShareName $DestShare - 
DestFilePath $DestPath -Context $context1 -DestContext $destcontext1 -Force
```

**It gives me error as below:**

Start-AzStorageFileCopy: The given path/prefix 'https:' is not a valid name for a file or directory or does match the requirement for Microsoft Azure File Service REST API.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please change the source and destination paths. In your particular scenario they should represent the path relative to the share.

```
$StorageAccountName = "z"
$StorageAccessKey = 
"md226fZvTKPKaCd9TxDGPn4mitCPfvBvgzElwoqIgpbf2Pe09GKKfNJlMcK2EXXqRLqOrhBslybaE1Cpz2BcPg=="
$context1=New-AzureStorageContext $StorageAccountName $StorageAccessKey

$DestStorageAccountName = "b"
$DestStorageAccessKey = "xZjU0r5g5fU+/ieAbwc22OmVtFY5BJdQuF8OZsFd7hGHYLzQFGg9ZCpsVnQi5u6Wi/nigb8jdupUGo0YaXBphg=="
$destcontext1=New-AzureStorageContext $DestStorageAccountName $DestStorageAccessKey
$SrcPath = "test.txt" #assuming the name of the source file is "test.txt"
$SrcShare = "y"
$DestPath = "test.txt" #assuming you want to copy the file and keep the same name
$DestShare = "a"
Start-AzureStorageFileCopy -SrcFilePath $SrcPath -SrcShareName $SrcShare -DestShareName $DestShare - 
DestFilePath $DestPath -Context $context1 -DestContext $destcontext1 -Force
```

From the documentation [`link`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azure.storage/start-azurestoragefilecopy?view=azurermps-6.13.0):

> **-SrcFilePath** Specifies the path of the source file relative to the source directory or source share.
>
> **-DestFilePath** Specifies the path of the destination file relative to the destination share.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. What if, I have a directory to copy? I have tried your way, but didn't work. :( Example: $SrcPath = "BVTSuite" $DestPath = "BVTSuite"

Comment: Unfortunately this Cmdlet will only work with files. In case of directories, you will have to do some extra work :). You will first need to enumerate all files and folders (recursively) in the source share and then copy files using this Cmdlet. Please note that this Cmdlet will not create a new directory so you will need to create a new directory (and sub directories) before you copy a file there.

Comment: Thank you so much. I thought the same. Will give it a try. Ticking this as correct answer. Thanks Again!

Comment: Awesome! Please post a new question if you run into any issues with that. BTW, you just upvoted the answer (I think) and not accepted it :).